# Storing Linked lists as a index in an Array C++

Tags: c++, graph, linked-list

Overview: Im currently attempting to write a code that will take a AOV Network graph and put it into a Linked List. I am how ever having trouble whats the best way to go about this. I understand on paper how graphs can be represented in the linked list form.

Here is the graph im going off of:

[image]

My Thought process/Pusdo code would be as follows:

> Create a Linked-List class that just adds the nodes and prints them out for the methods.
>   Then for each edge access the index of an array and go to that Linked list.
>   So then my array would have [s,a,d,g,b,e,h,c,f,i,t] where each letter would represent the >Linked list of that vertex. So if i would like to call the S vertex i would have to call the >0 element of the array and that would point to s Linked-List. Is there a easy implementation >of this in C++?

Here is my Linked-List Class right now:

```
class List{
private:
    typedef struct node{
        char vertex;
        node* next;
    }* nodePtr;
    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;
public:
    List();
    void AddNode(char AddData);
    void printList();
};

List::List(){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void List::AddNode(char AddData){
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->vertex = AddData;

    if(head != NULL){
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }
    else{
        head = n;
    }
}

void List::printList(){
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
        cout << curr->vertex << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Can Using a Double Linked List like this work?
[image]

Comment: You don't have to put all variables as class member variables. `curr` could easily be a local variable in the member functions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a data structure named Adjacent Table to store graph in a linkedlist structure

the element in AT is like

```
struct ATEle {
    char name;
    ATEle * neighborPointer;
    ATEle * nodelistPointer;
}
```

the nodes in the graph are organized in a linkedlist, and each node is also the head of a linked list of all its neighbors

e.g. we have a graph of 4 nodes, A, B, C, D, and A connects with B, C, D connects with A, B with C, D, in the adjancent table it looks like :

A -> B -> C

|

B -> C ->D

|

C

|

D -> A

Answer (score 0):

You have a graph problem, not a list problem.   Use the graph metaphors of "node" and "edge" instead of "list."